# How to concatenate or combine multiple cells with header

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to combine columns `a2` through to `z2` including the column header for each item and then apply to about 3500 rows.
It works when i enter `=A1&A2&"----"&B1&B2&"----"&C1&C2&"` for the first, however when i try to paste this into multiple cells it does not index and misses the header instead copying the cell above.
I need some kind of formula that will copy header and the columns a-z and understand when i paste that into every row i still want the header.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking to use [absolute cell references](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9). Following this link you will get to a page that has some good explaination.

So your formula would look like:

```
=A$1&A2&"----"&B$1&B2&"----"&C$1&C2.....
```

Now you can drag the formula down.

Note that when you have the rights to use [`TEXTJOIN`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) that would also be a nice way to go. Below is an example (made in GS since my work pc doesn't support TEXTJOIN, but you can get the same result in Excel)

[image]

So the formula in `A5` in Excel would be:

```
=TEXTJOIN("----",TRUE,$A$1:$E$1&A2:E2)
```

Entered as array through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Change ranges accordingly and drag down the formula

Comment: thankyou so much for the reply, what would be an example of using textjoin to do this? it seems i can do this?

Comment: I'll edit the answer @user1071811

Comment: ........................very nice ! ...............................

Comment: Missed that you included it.  I should read more.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following User Defined Function:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function SuperJoin(r1 As Range, r2 As Range) As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    i = r1.Count
    For j = 1 To i
        SuperJoin = SuperJoin & "----" & r1(1, j) & r2(1, j)
    Next j

    SuperJoin = Mid(SuperJoin, 5)
End Function
```

[image]

If you wanted to go all the way to column **Z**, you would use:

```
=SuperJoin(A1:Z1,A2:Z2)
```

Comment: thanks mate, you are very kind and have solved my issue

Comment: This is a nice way if you don't have access to `TEXTJOIN` :). It avoids a lot of concatenating.